# The Numbers Four and Seven

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

I'm going to ask a naïve question, a child's question, I do hope it is not voted down through lack of context,

All numbers have properties unique to them. The number four is the solution to the problem of the minimum way to colour a map so that no two colours touch whilst at the same time being the solution to the problem of the maximum degree of a polynomial that exhibits a general solution by radicals.

The number seven is the analogous solution to the problem of the minimum way to colour a torus so that no two colours touch.

Is there an analogous problem in which the number seven is a maximum, perhaps if one were able to define an analogue of polynomials on the torus or the like?

Thank you

Comment: The regular seven sided figure is the first non-constructable regular polygon, not sure if that fits your pattern.

Comment: Seven is the maximum dimension for a parallelizable sphere.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to expect that any analogy of "the problem of the maximum degree of a polynomial that exhibits a general solution by radicals" should have an "analogous problem" on the torus that gives $7$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers

Comment: Some nice answers and a good dose of scepticism from Travis. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I am still rather hoping for a connection with polynomials, but as Travis points out, that may be too much to ask :)

Comment: @Travis You have pointed me to some interesting things. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers!$\,\,\,$

Comment: A ladybug has at most 7 dots! :)